# Parse data from xml to be used in jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm writing a currency exchange widget and i can't get how to parse data from this xml:
http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

Here's my code:

```
jQuery('#value_from').on('keyup', function() {
    var data = this.value;
    var curr = document.getElementById('curr_from').value;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            jQuery(xml).find('Cube').each(function(){
                var data = jQuery(this).attr('currency');
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('value_to').value = '\u20AC ' + data;
});
```

Comment: jQuery should parse the XML automatically. Doesn't it? What does `console.log(xml)` reveal?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it says there's an xml parsing error

Comment: That's the exact complete output of `console.log(xml)`?

Comment: Where are you executing this code, if it is from a different domain it won't work without jsonp. [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario this is the complete output: `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{0874d6df-f4ec-4e0f-945c-1c357d83a4ce} Line Number 1, Column 1`. There's nothing in "response". You need to see the "headings" too?

Comment: @Danny yes of course, i'm working in localhost right now...but this sound kinda a no sense...xml are used a lot of times on other domains. I personally use them in similar situation, but with php scripts, without problem. This is the first time i'm trying to use it in jQuery...you mean i better go back and use php?

Comment: @Mariano php isnt executed in the browser hence why you can make calls to other domains. Javascript is executed on the user's machine and doesn't allow it for security reasons. You can write php to fetch that xml and then in the jQuery call your php that is hosted on the same domain.

Comment: @Danny thanks! didn't know this! server side request is the only way then...

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
jQuery(xml).find('cube')
```

to this:

```
jQuery(xml).find('Cube')
    //------------^-------uppercase 'C'
```

---

In your xml file i just seen that you have the xml node as **Cube** but you are finding it with lowercase `c` as **cube**.

---

### Note:

As this is a cross domain data access hence `dataType:"xml"` won't work here, as per docs cross domain data can be accessed only with `dataType:"jsonp"`.

Comment: Thanks, corrected but this wasn't the only problem. I've updated my question

Comment: @Mariano have you checked if they have set the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Comment: There's nothing like that in the header. But if it can be useful, i parse data from that same xml in a php script without problems